# Why is a projective variety 'the best kind'?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question

In Hartshorne's AG, he discusses the classification of curves by birational equivalence class  says 'based on the idea that a nonsingular projective variety is the best kind..'. What exactly makes a projective variety better than an affine one? I know for each class there is a unique nonsingular projective curve. While this may be a reason projective varieties are special it can't really serve as motivation for that section. I know projective varieties have nice intersection properties but that's not really intrinsic to the birational equivalence classes. Why shouldn't an affine variety serve as our model?

Comment: In short projective smooth varieties are best in every way.  Forget algebraic geometry for a moment, from complex geometric point of view they have finite dimensional homology, cohomology, Poincare pairing,  they have Hodge structures,  they good intersection theory (Bezout type theorems ) etc. Now serres GaGa tells you most if this structures is available in algebraic world. In other words these varieites are the most rich.  Affine varieties aren't good because there aren't too many of them.  Natural examples like elliptic curves, flag spaces, grassmanians are all projective.

Comment: In other words, affine varieties arent enough because most interesting examples that occur in nature are of projective kind. Because projective varieties carry so much structure it is often technically easier to handle them.